# How goes the Refined Harmonic Bin packing algorithm?

Tags: packing-problem

I failed to find any paper that explains the algorithm in a simple manner.

I understand Harmonic(M) which goes like this:
Size(1/K - 1/(K-1)] -> Type K-1 -> Pack K-1 per bin

at the end
Size(0 - 1/K) -> Use Next Fit

now i just need to understand what the difference is between Refined Harmonic and normal one

Comment: This is the originating paper: C. C. Lee and D. T. Lee. 1985. A simple on-line bin-packing algorithm. J. ACM 32, 3 (July 1985), 562-572. DOI=10.1145/3828.3833 http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/3828.3833